# How to get Radio button value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button, radio-group

I am using below code for the gender selection in a flutter application. In this, this is working fine, but I am not able to retrieve the value of gender in Text format. How should I do that?

```
final gender = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Radio(
            value: 0,
            groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
            onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
          ),
          Text("Male"),
          Radio(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
            onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
          ),
          Text("Female"),
          Radio(
            value: 2,
            groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
            onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
          ),
          Text("Other"),
        ],
      ),
    );

void _handleGenderChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _genderRadioBtnVal = value;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the values as 0,1,2 you get that in onChanged.If you want String values like "Male", "Female" and "other" you can change your value to String type and give them appropriate values.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Radio<String>(
        value: "Male",
        groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
        onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
      ),
      Text("Male"),
      Radio<String>(
        value: "Female",
        groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
        onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
      ),
      Text("Female"),
      Radio<String>(
        value: "Other",
        groupValue: _genderRadioBtnVal,
        onChanged: _handleGenderChange,
      ),
      Text("Other"),
    ],
  );

void _handleGenderChange(String value) {
  setState(() {
    _genderRadioBtnVal = value;
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. Was an amazing implementation.